# linux ”stress -i 10“ , top viewing CPU performance find io_wait not increase

Tags: linux, cpu, stress

Why does command "stress -i 2" not increase the io_wait value? Only the system call went up

[image]

Comment: image maybe can't view. Add the specific parameters: 
top - 17:33:38 up 33 days,  7:48,  3 users,  load average: 1.10, 0.91, 0.56
%Cpu(s):  0.7 us, 99.3 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st

Answer (score 0):

because of in vm host, stress -i call sync(), flush the cache to disk, but cache is less, so can not make iowait

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).